# Show percentiles of Variable A, while the classification of percentiles is based on Variable B

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

| INCOME | WEALTH |
| --- | --- |
| 10.000 | 100000 |
| 15.000 | 111000 |
| 14.200 | 123456 |
| 12.654 | 654321 |

I have many more rows.

I now want to now find how much INCOME a household in a specific WEALTH percentile has. The following quantiles are relevant:

```
c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95,0.99)
```

I have always used the following code to get specific percentile values:

```
a <- quantile(WEALTH, probs = c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95,0.99))
```

But now I want to base my percentiles on WEALTH but get the respective INCOME. I have tried the following code but the results are not plausible:

```
df$percentile = ntile(df$WEALTH,100)
df <- df[df$percentile %in% c(1,5,10,25,50,75,90,95,99), ]

a <- df %>% 
  group_by(percentile) %>% 
  summarise(max = max(INCOME))
```

The results that I get a not consistent with other parts of the analysis that I have done. I assume that the percentile when using the "quantile" function are calculated differently that simply taking the maximum.

Comment: I’ve provided an answer that might explain your issue. If it doesn’t, we may need more detail to understand the problem - could you [edit] your post to specify your expected output, your actual output, and your actual data (or at least, enough of a subset to demonstrate the problem)? For the data, run `dput(df)` in R and paste the result into your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if i understood your question correctly,
but the quantile has different methods of calculation. I for example always go for number 6, since this is what i was taought in my stat courses.

> **type:**  an integer between 1 and 9 selecting one of the nine quantile
> algorithms detailed below to be used.

Read more about different types by using `?quantile` commands (help on quantile)

Answer (score 0):

If you have fewer than 100 rows in your dataset, `dplyr::ntile(x, 100)` won’t yield accurate percentiles, but will only give you bins numbered through the total number of rows:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(percentile = ntile(WEALTH, 100))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  INCOME WEALTH percentile
   <dbl>  <dbl>      <int>
1   10   100000          1
2   15   111000          2
3   14.2 123456          3
4   12.7 654321          4
```

To get true percentiles, you can rescale the result, manually or with `scales::rescale()`:

```
library(scales)

df %>% 
  mutate(percentile = rescale(
    ntile(WEALTH, 100),
    c(1, 100)
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  INCOME WEALTH percentile
   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1   10   100000          1
2   15   111000         34
3   14.2 123456         67
4   12.7 654321        100
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it. However it seems to yield the same result as without rescaling.